# Why is this giving me a segfault?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

This:

```
bool grid[1280][1024];
for (int x = 0; x<1280; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y<1024; y++)
    {
        grid[x][y] = false;
    }
}
```

works fine, but

```
bool grid[1280][1024];
bool grid2[1280][1024];

for (int x = 0; x<1280; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y<1024; y++)
    {
        grid[x][y] = false;
        grid2[x][y] = false;
    }
}
```

gives me a segfault. Why?

Comment: Did you try running it with **gdb**?

Comment: segfault or stack overflow? It looks more like stack overflow to me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not enough stack space, your second example also crashes on my PC. Try allocating on the heap, or even better, use a proper container class:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

typedef std::array<bool, 1280> line;

int main()
{
    std::vector<line> grid(1024);
    std::vector<line> grid2(1024);

    // no initialization to false necessary
}
```

Note how I switched the width and the height. You probably want your elements aligned this way to ensure fast linear access.

Comment: @Data: You can edit your question and include the new code as well to have it discussed, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think `sizeof(bool)` is defined as being the same as `sizeof(char)`. Assuming a `char` takes one byte on the system you're on, that second example attempts to allocate `2*1280*1024` bytes on the stack. ***That's 2.5MB.*** Your system might not provide that much stack space.

Use one of the contaienrs from the standard library which use heap space to store their data.

Comment: @Joe: That was my internal default locale kicking in. Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, no segfaults on either using g++ 4.2.1, have you tried these examples alone?

Comment: Yep, making a new console application causes the same thing. I get the Windows 7 'this application has stopped working' box. Using the debugger alerts me to a 'Segmentation Fault'.

Comment: I've just tried it on Visual Studio 2008 on server 2003 and i too get that error, can i recomend cygwin, so you can use g++

Answer (score 1):

Probably stack overflow. Create the array dynamically, it will work (because it will be created on the heap). Or, use `std::vector< std::vector< char > >`, instead. ( be **very** careful, if you decide to use `std::vector< bool >`.. unless you don't know what **exactly** you're doing (it's **not** normal STL container, containing just bools), use it with char ).

Using `std::vector< std::vector< char > >` will let you use the object as normal two-dimensional array.

---

**EDIT:**
**std::vector< bool >:** "This specialization is provided to optimize for space allocation: In this template specialization, each element occupies only one bit (which is eight times less than the smallest type in C++: char).

The references to elements of a bool vector returned by the vector members are not references to bool objects, but a special member type which is a reference to a single bit, defined inside the vector class specialization as". [CPlusPlus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)